# Titanium.Android.Intent share on social media

Tags: android, facebook, android-intent, titanium, share

I'm developing an App that shares news on "Only" native apps like Facebook, Twitter and LinkedIn.

I can't make intent shares custom to display only the apps I stated before. And using custom modules open apps in the browser.

I'm using titanium...
So any help with this?

Thanks.

Comment: So you want intent which shares data to only Facebook, Twitter and LinkedIn or all native apps in a particular device which can handle share functionality like whatsapp, etc.

Comment: Yes I want it to just share in Facebook, Twitter and LinkedIn. Using intent shares in all apps installed in that particular device, so I made my custom window to just display those 3 apps, but I couldn't make it open the native app and share on it's wall. And using modules won't open the native app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using the following intents to share on native Facebook and twitter apps:

```
var intFB = Ti.Android.createIntent({
    action : Ti.Android.ACTION_SEND,
    packageName : "com.facebook.katana",                        
    type : "text/plain"
});                    

intFB.putExtra(Ti.Android.EXTRA_TEXT, yourLink);
//facebook only supports LINKS(!!!)
Ti.Android.currentActivity.startActivity(intFB);

var intTwitter = Ti.Android.createIntent({
    action: Ti.Android.ACTION_SEND,
    packageName: "com.twitter.android",     
    flags: Ti.Android.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK,
    type: "text/plain"
});

intTwitter.putExtra( Ti.Android.EXTRA_TEXT, yourMessage); 
//twitter supports any kind of string content (link, text, etc)
Ti.Android.currentActivity.startActivity( intTwitter );
```

Comment: Thanks Jeroen, it works, but if the app is not installed it throws an exception, So I used native modules in that case, Thanks again..